# GCC compiler missing libraries? Raspberry OS 32 Bit latest

Tags: gcc, raspbian

I'm trying to compile a PiStorm binaries for an Amiga project. During compilation I get this error:

```
gcc -o emulator emulator.o memory_mapped.o config_file/config_file.o config_file/rominfo.o input/input.o gpio/ps_protocol.o platforms/platforms.o platforms/amiga/amiga-autoconf.o platforms/amiga/amiga-platform.o platforms/amiga/amiga-registers.o platforms/amiga/amiga-interrupts.o platforms/mac68k/mac68k-platform.o platforms/dummy/dummy-platform.o platforms/dummy/dummy-registers.o platforms/amiga/Gayle.o platforms/amiga/hunk-reloc.o platforms/amiga/cdtv-dmac.o platforms/amiga/rtg/rtg.o platforms/amiga/rtg/rtg-output-raylib.o platforms/amiga/rtg/rtg-gfx.o platforms/amiga/piscsi/piscsi.o platforms/amiga/ahi/pi_ahi.o platforms/amiga/pistorm-dev/pistorm-dev.o platforms/amiga/net/pi-net.o platforms/shared/rtc.o platforms/shared/common.o m68kcpu.o m68kdasm.o softfloat/softfloat.o softfloat/softfloat_fpsp.o m68kops.o a314/a314.o -O3 -pthread -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -L/opt/vc/lib -L./raylib -lraylib -lbrcmGLESv2 -lbrcmEGL -lbcm_host -lstdc++ -lvcos -lvchiq_arm -lasound -lm -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbrcmGLESv2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbrcmEGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:69: emulator] Error 1
```

Would anyone know what libraries I'm missing?

https://github.com/captain-amygdala/pistorm/wiki/PiStorm-Software-Installation

tried with OS Lite, 32 bit, 64 bit, Full Raspberry Pi OS, same error